# SAP B1 query using pivot for yearly comparison

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

**Requirement**: I want to compare the years(2018) sales and gross profit over last year(2017).
**Solution:** I have tried using the query below and I get the expected results.

```
Month | prevSales | prevGP    | currentSales | currGP
Jan   | 1234567.00| 1234567.00| 1234567.00   | 1234567.00
Feb   | 1234567.00| 1234567.00| 1234567.00   | 1234567.00
```

**Problem:** The query took so long to produce results, it's almost one minute to display results.

```
SELECT P.[monName],
      ISNULL([2017],0) as [prev],
      ISNULL(P.[prevGP],0) [prevGP],
      ISNULL([2018],0) as [curr],
      ISNULL(P.[currGP],0) [currGP]
FROM (
    SELECT  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,T1.DocDate),3) [monName], 
            MONTH(T1.DocDate) [monNum], 
            ROUND((T1.Doctotal-T1.VatSum-T1.TotalExpns),0) AS [BAL],
            (SELECT Sum(A.GrosProfit) 
                FROM OINV A 
                WHERE A.CANCELED='N' AND A.DocStatus='C' AND RIGHT(A.NumAtCard,9)<>'CANCELLED' 
                AND YEAR(A.DocDate)=YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AND MONTH(A.DocDate)=MONTH(T1.DocDate) ) [prevGP],
            (SELECT SUM(B.GrosProfit) 
                FROM OINV B 
                WHERE B.CANCELED='N' AND B.DocStatus='C' AND RIGHT(B.NumAtCard,9)<>'CANCELLED' 
                AND YEAR(B.DocDate)=YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(B.DocDate)=MONTH(T1.DocDate) ) [currGP],
            year(T1.Docdate) as [year]
    FROM dbo.OCRD T0
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OINV T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode  
    Where RIGHT(T1.Numatcard,9)<>'CANCELLED' AND T1.CANCELED='N' 
    AND T0.[CardType] ='C' AND T1.DocStatus='C' 
    ) S
PIVOT  ( SUM(S.[BAL]) FOR [year] IN ([2017],[2018])) P
```

What could I possibly do to make the ***query efficient***. I believe there is something to do with the ***pivot***. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your view are the subqueries. If you want to improve the performance of your query you need to avoid the use of those subqueries.

For example, you can create an sql view that returns the information you need. Then you join your current query with that view and you remove the subqueries.

You could do it like this.

```
create view InvoiceInfoByMonth
as
select sum(GrosProfit) as GrosProfit, year(docdate) as DocYear, month(docdate) as DocMonth
from OINV 
WHERE CANCELED='N' AND DocStatus='C' AND RIGHT(NumAtCard,9)<>'CANCELLED' 
group by year(DocDate), month(DocDate)
GO
SELECT P.[monName],
      ISNULL([2017],0) as [prev],
      ISNULL(P.[prevGP],0) [prevGP],
      ISNULL([2018],0) as [curr],
      ISNULL(P.[currGP],0) [currGP]
FROM (
    SELECT  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,T1.DocDate),3) [monName], 
            MONTH(T1.DocDate) [monNum], 
            ROUND((T1.Doctotal-T1.VatSum-T1.TotalExpns),0) AS [BAL],
            T2.GrosProfit as prevGP, T3.GrosProfit as currGP,
            year(T1.Docdate) as [year]
    FROM dbo.OCRD T0
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OINV T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode  
    left join InvoiceInfoByMonth T2 ON T2.DocYear = year(getdate())-1 and month(T1.DocDate) = T2.DocMonth
    left join InvoiceInfoByMonth T3 ON T3.DocYear = year(getdate()) and month(T1.DocDate) = T3.DocMonth
    Where RIGHT(T1.Numatcard,9)<>'CANCELLED' AND T1.CANCELED='N' 
    AND T0.[CardType] ='C' AND T1.DocStatus='C' 
    ) S
PIVOT  ( SUM(S.[BAL]) FOR [year] IN ([2017],[2018])) P
```

In my system, the query execution time improved from 1 minute to 1 second.